# Ground state of Bogoliubov quasi-particles

Tags: operators, hilbert-space, superconductivity, second-quantization, ground-state

Consider a set of boson/fermion creation and annihilation operators satisfying the canonical (anti-)commutation rules (CCR/CAR):

$$
[a_i, a_j]_\eta
= [a^\dagger_i, a^\dagger_j]_\eta = 0, 
\quad
[a_i, a^\dagger_j]_\eta 
= \delta_{ij}
\quad (i,j = 1,...,N)
$$

where $\eta$ is the statistical sign ($+1$ for boson, and $-1$ for fermion), $[A,B]_\eta = AB - \eta BA$, and $N$ is the dimension of one-particle Hilbert space. A general **canonical transformation** mixes the creation and annihilation operators to produce a new set of bosons/fermions $\{b_j\}_{j=1}^N$, which I call the *Bogoliubov quasi-particles*:

$$
b_i = \sum_{j=1}^N 
(u_{ij} a_j + v_{ij} a^\dagger_j)
, \quad
b^\dagger_i = \sum_{j=1}^N 
(v^*_{ij} a_j + u^*_{ij} a^\dagger_j)
$$

and the $\{b_i\}$ operators should also satisfy the CCR/CAR:

$$
[b_i, b_j]_\eta
= [b^\dagger_i, b^\dagger_j]_\eta = 0, 
\quad
[b_i, b^\dagger_j]_\eta 
= \delta_{ij}
\quad (i,j = 1,...,N)
$$

One can show that to preserve the CCR/CAR, the matrices $U = \{u_{ij}\}$, $V = \{v_{ij}\}$ should satisfy the requirement

$$
U V^{\mathsf{T}} = \eta V U^{\mathsf{T}} \quad \text{and} \quad
U U^\dagger - \eta V V^\dagger = 1
$$

**Question**: Let $|0_a\rangle, |0_b\rangle$ be the vacuum states of the $a, b$ particles respectively, i.e.

$$
\forall i = 1,...,N: \quad
a_i |0_a\rangle = 0, \quad
b_i |0_b\rangle = 0
$$

How to express $|0_b\rangle$ in terms of states and operators of the $a$ particles?

Comment: It's a bit more than an "educated guess," but it it does require that the $U$ matrix be invertible, which is not globally true. For the Bosonic case look at https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.03289 eq 2.17 2.18

Comment: I found [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0908.0787) useful at one point. Not sure that it really gets at what you're looking for, but it might help.

Comment: You can check this paper by Kita https://journals.jps.jp/doi/abs/10.1143/JPSJ.65.908. You can find the same calculation also in his book: http://link.springer.com/10.1007/978-4-431-55405-9
The result is similar to the one in Mike Stone's note.

Comment: @skdys Could you please specify at which chapter the *derivation* of the ground state of quasi-particles is given? I had a brief look but did not find it.

Comment: In the book, Eq. 8.4 is the definition of a many-body wavefunction $\vert {\Phi} \rangle$ as a function of a matrix $\phi$. In Sec. 8.3, the standard BdG equations are derived, and finally, after Eq. 8.46, the connection between this matrix $\phi$ and the usual coherence factor u and v is shown. I believe that if you reorder the steps (maybe with the help of the paper), you can get to a formal mathematical derivation if that is your objective.
To me, this looks pretty formal already from a physicist's point of view.

Comment: Take into account that you are not really looking at the ground state of the "quasiparticles". I don't really know if that wording is even the correct one. $\vert \Phi \rangle$  is the many-body ground state of the electron gas. 

Quasiparticles are, per definition, the excitations of the ground state.

This version of the derivation of BdG transformations starts with an ansatz about $\vert \Phi  \rangle $ and then derives the equations for the variational minimization. It is basically a generalization of the original BCS derivation for arbitrary pairing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is summarized from two notes (both can be found [here](http://people.physics.illinois.edu/stone/)) by Prof. Michael Stone (@mikestone). Confusing typos in these notes are corrected.

From a general perspective, the two set of operators $\{a\}, \{b\}$ are two realizations of the CCR/CAR. By the [Stone-von Neumann theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93von_Neumann_theorem), there is a *unitary operator* $\mathcal{U}$ that acts on the many-body Hilbert space such that

$$
b_i = \mathcal{U} a_i \mathcal{U}^\dagger
\ \Rightarrow \ 
b^\dagger_i = \mathcal{U} a^\dagger_i \mathcal{U}^\dagger
$$

Then we find $|0_b\rangle \propto \mathcal{U}|0_a\rangle$, since

$$
a_i |0_a\rangle 
= \mathcal{U}^\dagger b_j \mathcal{U} |0_a\rangle = 0
$$

However, as noted by Prof. Stone, the general form of $\mathcal{U}$ is very complicated. Thus we take another approach.

*Assume that $U$ is invertible* (this is *not* an "innocent assumption"). Then $b_i |0_b \rangle = 0$ is equivalent to

$$
0 = U^{-1}_{ij} b_j |0_b\rangle
= (a_i - S_{ij} a^\dagger_j) |0_b \rangle, 
\quad
S \equiv - U^{-1} V
$$

Using the constraint $U V^\mathsf{T} = \eta V U^\mathsf{T}$, one can show that

$$
S^\mathsf{T} = \eta S
$$

i.e. the matrix $S$ is symmetric for bosons, and anti-symmetric for fermions. Then we construct the bilinear

$$
Q \equiv \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i,j}
S_{ij} a^\dagger_i a^\dagger_j
$$

and use the BCH formula to calculate

$$
\begin{equation*}
    e^Q a_i e^{-Q}
    = a_i + [Q,a_i]
    + \frac{1}{2}[Q,[Q,a_i]]
    + \cdots
\end{equation*}
$$

Fortunately, the commutator

$$
[Q, a_i] = - S_{ij} a^\dagger_j
$$

commutes with $Q$ (for both bosons and fermions). Therefore we simply get

$$
\begin{equation*}
    e^Q a_i e^{-Q} 
    = a_i + [Q,a_i]
    = a_i - S_{ij} a^\dagger_j
\end{equation*}
$$

and $b_i |0_b \rangle = 0$ is equivalent to

$$
e^Q a_i e^{-Q} |0_b\rangle = 0
$$

This can be satisfied by all $a_i$ *if and only if*

$$
e^{-Q} |0_b \rangle \propto |0_a \rangle
$$

The "if" is obvious. To show "only if", suppose that $|\psi\rangle \equiv e^{-Q} |0_b \rangle \ne |0_a \rangle$; then $e^Q$, which consists of only $\{a^\dagger_i\}$, cannot annihilate $|\psi\rangle$. Finally, up to a normalization constant $\mathcal{N}$, the vacuum $|0_b\rangle$ is

$$
|0_b\rangle = \mathcal{N} e^Q |0_a \rangle
$$

(When I have time I will update on finding $\mathcal{N}$.)