# Ground state of Bogoliubov quasi-particles (simpler version)

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, superconductivity, second-quantization, ground-state

This is a simplified version of [one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/736101/222821) of my previous questions. Let $b_1, b_2$ be two boson operators; their vacuum is denoted as $|0\rangle$, i.e. $b_i |0\rangle = 0$. We can make a canonical Bogoliubov transformation:

$$
\beta_1 = u b_1 + v b^\dagger_2, \quad
\beta_2 = u b_2 + v b^\dagger_1
$$

where $u,v$ are two real positive numbers. $u^2 - v^2 = 1$ to make sure that $\beta_i$ are still bosons, i.e. satisfy the canonical commutation relations. Now I want to find the vacuum $|0_\beta\rangle$ of $\beta_1, \beta_2$, i.e. $\beta_i |0\rangle = 0$. I know the answer is (up to a normalization constant)

$$
|0_\beta\rangle = e^Q |0\rangle, \quad
Q = -\frac{v}{u} b^\dagger_1 b^\dagger_2
\tag{1}
$$

which I found by an educated guess (see an alternative way to get it in this [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/764131/222821)).

To get $|0_\beta\rangle$ more naturally, I attempt to use *projections*: we should be able to get $|0_\beta\rangle$ starting from any state $|\psi\rangle$ that is *not orthogonal* to $|0_\beta\rangle$ by projecting out all states with number of $\beta_i$ greater than 0. In this spirit, we should have

$$
|0_\beta\rangle
\propto \prod_{n=1}^\infty 
(\beta^\dagger_1 \beta_1 - n)
(\beta^\dagger_2 \beta_2 - n) |\psi\rangle
\tag{2}
$$

This method works for fermions (see Eqs. (1.33), (1,34) in [*D-wave Superconductivity*](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/dwave-superconductivity/25FAA6DC672ACB1D79A008BCD78F8C63) by Xiang et al), for which one can simply choose $|\psi\rangle$ as the vacuum of the original fermions. But for bosons things are much more complicated due to the infinite product; and one *cannot* choose $|\psi\rangle = |0\rangle$, since $\langle 0_\beta | 0 \rangle = \langle 0 | \exp(Q^\dagger) | 0 \rangle = 0$ (as noted by @Quantum Mechanic; since $Q^\dagger$ only contains annihilation operators).

Question: How to derive Eq. (1) from Eq. (2), and how may we choose a convenient $|\psi\rangle$?

Answer (score 1):

The Bogoliubov transformation is achieved by a [two-mode squeezing operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeezed_coherent_state#Two-mode_squeezed_states) that achieves
$$S b_i S^\dagger=\beta_i.$$ Using this and the definition of the vacuum $b_i|0\rangle=0$, one finds
$$0=S b_i|0\rangle=S b_i S^\dagger S|0\rangle=\beta_i S|0\rangle.$$ We thus learn that the null eigenstate of the operator $\beta_i$ is simply the squeezed vacuum state $S|0\rangle$. Up to proportionality constants and braiding relations, that is what's given by $e^Q|0\rangle$.

That's the easiest method for me. In terms of your projections method, one might have to worry about the state where the projections start: you need some proof that $|0\rangle$ has nonzero overlap with $|0_\beta\rangle$ because otherwise the projection will vanish.

Comment: Can one *derive* the squeezing operator $S$ from first principles?

Comment: @ZhengyuanYue Yes! It must be an element of SU(1,1) because it performs an SU(1,1) transformation on the operators $b_i$. The Lie algebra of su(1,1) and its Lie group SU(1,1) are essential here

Comment: Can this be generalized to more than 2 bosons? You may refer to my ["complete" version](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/736101/222821) of the question and see if you have additional comments to the existing ones there.

Comment: @ZhengyuanYue I'm not sure if there's a direct way, but my easy way to generalize is to do a ("linear" or "beam splitter") transformation $Ua_iU^\dagger=\sum_j u_{ij}a_j$ either before or after the $S$ (Bogoliubov) transformation and then see how that changes the $\beta_i$, the $S$ operator, etc.